# Qcamera Unsuported media type "{}"

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy investigando sobre el uso del Widget QCamera y derivados, al hacer un pequeño ejercicio de una aplicacion para tomar fotografias con la WebCam me arroja un aviso la consola el cual es este:

```
Unsupported media type: "{32595559-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{32595559-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{32595559-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{32595559-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{32595559-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{32595559-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
Unsupported media type: "{47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}"
```

La aplicacion funciona bien toma las fotos y las guarda sin problema pero no se que signifque esto, y si hay alguna manera de corregirlo

este es el codigo

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QToolBar,QAction,QComboBox
from PyQt5.Qt import QCameraInfo,QCameraViewfinder,QCamera,QCameraImageCapture
import os

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ListaCamaras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()

        self.Finder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.Finder.show()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Finder)

        self.Selecion_camara(0)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Camara")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        AccionFoto = QAction("Tomar Foto",self)
        AccionFoto.setStatusTip("Tomar foto")
        AccionFoto.triggered.connect(self.take_photo)
        toolbar.addAction(AccionFoto)

        box = QComboBox()
        box.addItems([c.description() for c in self.ListaCamaras])
        box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.Selecion_camara)

        toolbar.addWidget(box)

    def Selecion_camara(self,i):
        self.camara = QCamera(self.ListaCamaras[i])
        self.camara.setViewfinder(self.Finder)
        self.camara.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        self.camara.start()

        self.captura = QCameraImageCapture(self.camara)
        self.captura.imageCaptured.connect(lambda d,i: self.status.showMessage("Imagen ok"))
        self.current_camera = self.ListaCamaras[i].description()
        self.save_seq = 0

    def take_photo(self):
        self.captura.capture(os.path.join())

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hola, funciona bien? porque cuando llamas al método capture no le pones nombre a la imagen, de hecho debe dar un error porque la función join no tiene argumentos. Adicionalmente, self.status no existe, para poder acceder a la barra de estado debería ser self.statusBar().showMessage("Imagen ok"). Y una vez modificado eso me funciona sin darme ningún warning

Comment: @Kayzh3r, si funciona bien de hecho el aviso que sale lo muestra en cuanto la camra empieza a grabar por asi decirlo,

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez Probablemente el warning señale que Qt intenta utilizar alguna característica que el driver de la cámara no soporte.